# Parent folder in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website with an old structure and I need to change its structure.

http://localhost/enc/pdfs/ : which contains some html files that i upload via ajax to put on tabbed div using.

```
    var Tabs = {
                'part1' : 'http://www.bsafer.com/enc/pdfs/part1.html',
...
            }
```

the js file is in the folder : ...enc/wp-content/themes/twentyten/

everything was working ok with this structure.

I need to make this new structure:

......./enc/wp-content/themes/twentyten/pdfs/ for htmls files.

......./enc/wp-content/themes/twentyten/js/ for the js file.

So I changed the js code to :

```
    var Tabs = {
                'part1' : '../pdfs/part1.html',

....
            }
```

The url for the script is set correctly and I can see it in the code source.

Why it is not working even ../ means returning to parent folder?

Thanks for helping me in this issue, URLs are really making me waste time.

please to note that I am working in localhost and that I am not allowed to use localhost in my adresses, and I need 15 reputation to post more than 2 links.

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

You may want to use a `BASE` tag, and then give the full address (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/base.html).  Of course, if you do this, you will need to change all of the URLs to relative URL's, because it will prepend the base to every URL link on the page.

It is hard to tell without looking at your code, but the Javascript ajax may not work with the `BASE` tag.  (I haven't tried it before with AJAZ).  However, it should work if you pull the anchor `attr` with your javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback, I am learning now about the notions you provided with. I will be back here to give details.

Comment: I hope it works well for you.  By the way, your link at the top only directs me to a parked Godaddy page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have got good knowledge concerning BASE and I will use it in the future to better time optimization but my problem is resolved simply by adressing directly the folder. Thank you anyway. sometimes even the solution is stupid, digging to find it make us learn. :-)

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out.  You always have the options to make the hypertext reference relationaly or absolutely.